# implode PHP em LUA

Tags: lua

Tenho o seguinte código que passa um array php para JS:

```
var js_array_date1 = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $newarray_date1).'"' ?>];
```

O meu problema é como posso fazer isso em LUA. Passar um array LUA para JS, sei que tenho de usar o `table.concat()`

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer, qual o problema em usar o `table.concat()`? já tentou algo assim? `meuArray = table.concat({"foo", "bar", "baz"})`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi(corriga-me se eu estiver errado), você precisa de uma função que dado um vetor V e um separador S, retorna uma string com cada um dos elementos em V concatenados em ordem e separados por S, em LUA temos a função table.concat()(http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableLibraryTutorial)
Ela existe em varia formas, a saber:

```
--Sem separador
> = table.concat({ 1, 2, "three", 4, "five" })
12three4five
--Com separador
> = table.concat({ 1, 2, "three", 4, "five" }, ", ")
1, 2, three, 4, five
--Com separador e indice inicial inclusivo (indices em LUA começam em 1)
> = table.concat({ 1, 2, "three", 4, "five" }, ", ", 2)
2, three, 4, five
--Com separador, indice inicial e final (inclusivos)
> = table.concat({ 1, 2, "three", 4, "five" }, ", ", 2, 4)
2, three, 4
```

Fonte:http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableLibraryTutorial
Note que essa função não funciona no caso de tabelas aninhadas